# XSLT - recursive algorithm with string-after to manipulate strings

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, substring

I need some help trying to "explode" a path where I only want to retrieve the end of it (filename).

For instance, here's the type of input xml I have to deal with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Program Files\XenData\Archive Series\Reports\AllDate.xsl"?>
<tape>
<titleheader>Some data</titleheader>
<titleheader2>Barcode:xxxx</titleheader2>
<profile><filename> /this/path/to/some/SHEET.mov </filename></profile>
<profile><filename> /another/path/to/stuff.mov </filename></profile>
...
</tape>
...
<tape>
...
</tape>
```

In the above, I need to grab "SHEET", and "stuff" (without anything before, and without the '.mov').

Not sure why it won't work - maybe I just did not understand the usage of template and the way xsl deals with returning values?

**Here's my XSL attempt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xmlns:XslUtils="java:com.dalet.ip.XslUtils"  xmlns:myfunc="/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="XslUtils myfunc">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>



   <xsl:template match="/">



            <xsl:for-each select="//tape">
                <xsl:variable name="tapeHeader2"><xsl:value-of select="./titleheader2"/></xsl:variable>
                <!--<header2><xsl:value-of select="$tapeHeader2"/></header2>-->
                <Barcode><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($tapeHeader2, 'Barcode:')"/></Barcode>

                <xsl:for-each select="//profile">
                <Title>
                        <xsl:variable name="itemCode"><xsl:value-of select="./filename"/></xsl:variable>
                        <header2><xsl:value-of select="$itemCode"/></header2>

                        <xsl:variable name="itemC"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($itemCode, '.mov'))"/></xsl:variable>

                        <-!-- calling template to explode the path -->  
                        <fileKey>
                                <xsl:call-template name="extractItemCode">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="datastring"><xsl:value-of select="$itemC"/></xsl:with-param>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </fileKey>

                </Title>
                </xsl:for-each>        

            </xsl:for-each> 

    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="extractItemCode">
        <xsl:param name="datastring"/>


        <xsl:if test="starts-with($datastring,'/')">

            <xsl:call-template name="extractItemCode">
                <xsl:with-param name="datastring"><xsl:value-of  select="substring-after($datastring,'/')"/></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> In the above, I need to grab "SHEET", and "stuff" (without anything
>   before, and without the '.mov').

How about:

```
<xsl:template name="extractFilename">
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($path, '/')">
            <xsl:call-template name="extractFileName">
                <xsl:with-param name="path" select="substring-after($path, '/')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($path, '.')" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problems with your template logic is that you need to test for [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains) instead of whether it starts with "/" and you need to actually return the value instead of making another recursive call when there are no more "/" left.

```
<xsl:template name="extractItemCode">
    <xsl:param name="datastring"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($datastring,'/')">          
            <xsl:call-template name="extractItemCode">
                <xsl:with-param name="datastring" select="substring-after($datastring,'/')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$datastring"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0, which you have declared in your stylesheet, then you don't need to use a recursive template. You can [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) on the "/", and select the `last()` item in the sequence to get the filename. Then select `substring-before()` '.mov'.

```
<fileKey>                            
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                            tokenize(normalize-space(filename), '/')[last()], 
                            '.mov')"/>
</fileKey>
```

You could also [`xsl:analyze-string`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string)

```
<fileKey>                            
  <xsl:analyze-string select="filename" regex=".*/(.*)\..*$">
     <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
   </xsl:analyze-string>    
</fileKey>
```